# рассчититать стоимость заказа

Tags: javascript

```js
/**

 * Класс, объекты которого описывают параметры гамбургера.

 *

 * @constructor

 * @param size Размер

 * @param stuffing Начинка

 * @throws {HamburgerException} При неправильном использовании

 */
//var orderHamburger = {
    //SIZE_SMALL: "SIZE_SMALL",
    //SIZE_LARGE: "SIZE_LARGE",
    //STUFFING_CHEESE: "STUFFING_CHEESE",
    //STUFFING_SALAD: "STUFFING_SALAD",
    //STUFFING_POTATO: "STUFFING_POTATO",
    //TOPPING_ONION: "TOPPING_ONION",
    //TOPPING_SPICE: "TOPPING_SPICE"
//};
var orderHamburger = {
        SIZE_SMALL: {param: "SIZE_SMALL", price: 50, calorie: 20},
        SIZE_LARGE: {param: "SIZE_LARGE", price: 100, calorie: 40},
        STUFFING_CHEESE: {param: "STUFFING_CHEESE", price: 10, calorie: 20},
        STUFFING_SALAD: {param: "STUFFING_SALAD", price: 20, calorie: 5},
        STUFFING_POTATO: {param: "STUFFING_POTATO", price: 15, calorie: 5},
        TOPPING_ONION: {param: "TOPPING_ONION", price: 20, calorie: 5},
        TOPPING_SPICE: {param: "TOPPING_SPICE", price: 15, calorie: 0}
    };

function Hamburger(size, stuffing) {
    if (!!size.param && !!stuffing.param) {
        this.init(size, stuffing);
    } else {
        console.log("Ошибка инициализации");
    }
}

Hamburger.prototype.init = function (size, stuffing) {
    this.params = {
        size: size,
        stuffing: stuffing,
        topping: []
    };
};

/* Размеры, виды начинок и добавок */
/**

 * Добавить добавку к гамбургеру. Можно добавить несколько

 * добавок, при условии, что они разные.

 *

 * @param topping Тип добавки

 * @throws {HamburgerException} При неправильном использовании

 */
// Добавить добавку
Hamburger.prototype.addTopping = function (topping) {
    var thisTopping = this.params.topping;
    var isPresent = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < thisTopping.length; i++) {
        if (thisTopping[i].param === topping.param) {
            isPresent++;
        }
    }
    if (!isPresent) {
        thisTopping.push(topping);
    } else {
        console.log("Такая добавка уже есть")
    }
};

/**

 * Убрать добавку, при условии, что она ранее была

 * добавлена.

 *

 * @param topping Тип добавки

 * @throws {HamburgerException} При неправильном использовании

 */
// Убрать добавку
Hamburger.prototype.removeTopping = function (topping) {
    var thisTopping = this.params.topping;

    for (var i = 0; i < thisTopping.length; i++) {
        if (thisTopping[i].param === topping.param) {
            delete thisTopping[i];
        }
    }
};
/**

 * Получить список добавок.

 *

 * @return {Array} Массив добавленных добавок, содержит константы

 * Hamburger.TOPPING_*

 */
// Получить список добавок
Hamburger.prototype.getToppings = function () {
    return this.params.topping;
};

/**

 * Узнать размер гамбургера

 */
// Узнать размер
Hamburger.prototype.getSize = function () {
    return this.params.size.param;
};
/**

 * Узнать начинку гамбургера

 */
// Узнать начинку
Hamburger.prototype.getStuffing = function () {
    return this.params.stuffing.param;
};

/**

 * Узнать цену гамбургера

 * @return {Number} Цена в тугриках

 */
// Узнать цену гамбургера
Hamburger.prototype.calculatePrice = function () {
    var thisParams = this.params;
    var totalPrice;
    var mainPrice = thisParams.size.price;
    var stuffPrice = thisParams.stuffing.price;
    var toppingPrice = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < thisParams.topping.length; i++) {
        toppingPrice += thisParams.topping[i].price;
    }
    totalPrice = mainPrice + stuffPrice + toppingPrice;

    return totalPrice
};
/**

 * Узнать калорийность

 * @return {Number} Калорийность в калориях

 */
Hamburger.prototype.calculateCalories = function () {
    var thisParams = this.params;
    var totalCalories;
    var mainPrice = thisParams.size.calorie;
    var stuffPrice = thisParams.stuffing.calorie;
    var toppingPrice = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < thisParams.topping.length; i++) {
        toppingPrice += thisParams.topping[i].calorie;
    }
    totalCalories = mainPrice + stuffPrice + toppingPrice;

    return totalCalories
};

var hamburger1 = new Hamburger ();

// result
console.log("----- Задача 12 ----- \n\n");
console.log("Размер", hamburger1.getSize());
console.log("Начинка", hamburger1.getStuffing());
console.log("calculatePrice", hamburger1.calculatePrice());
console.log("calculateCalories", hamburger1.calculateCalories());

console.log(hamburger1.getToppings());
hamburger1.addTopping(orderHamburger.TOPPING_ONION);
console.log(hamburger1.getToppings());
hamburger1.addTopping(orderHamburger.TOPPING_SPICE);
console.log("getToppings", hamburger1.getToppings());
console.log("removeTopping", hamburger1.removeTopping(orderHamburger.TOPPING_ONION));
console.log("getToppings", hamburger1.getToppings());
console.log("\n");

function OrderHamburger() {

    if (document.getElementById('bigSize').checked == true) {
        Hamburger(orderHamburger.SIZE_LARGE);
    } else {
    }
    if (document.getElementById('smallSize').checked == true) {
        Hamburger(orderHamburger.SIZE_SMALL);
    } else {
    }
    var insertionQuantity = document.getElementById('nachinka').getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < insertionQuantity.length; i++){
        if (insertionQuantity[i].checked === true){
            Hamburger.price = Hamburger.price + additionalPrice[i];
            Hamburger.energy = Hamburger.energy + additionalEnergy[i];
        }
    }

    Hamburger.price = Hamburger.price + additionalPrice[i];
    Hamburger.energy = Hamburger.energy + additionalEnergy[i];

    document.getElementById('burgerPrice').innerHTML = Hamburger.price;
    document.getElementById('burgerEnergy').innerHTML = Hamburger.energy;
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

#form {
    display: block;
    width: 350px;
    margin: 15px auto 0;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

legend {
    font-size: 17px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.radio-variant {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 47%;
}

.row {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

input[type=submit] {
    padding: 4px 15px 6px;
}

#message {
    height: 28px
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ST.css">
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
    <div class="row">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Create Hamburger</legend>
            <div id="burgerSize" class="checkbox-variant">Выберите размер бургера:<br>
                <input type="radio" name="size" id="smallSize">маленький (50 тугриков, 20 ккал)<br>
                <input type="radio" name="size" id="bigSize">большой (100 тугриков, 40 ккал)<br>
            </div>
            <div id="nachinka" class="checkbox-variant">
                Выберите начинку:<br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="CHEESE">сыр (+ 10 тугриков, + 20 ккал)<br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="SALAD">салат (+ 20 тугриков, + 5 ккал)<br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="POTATO">ветчина (+ 10 тугриков, + 50 ккал)<br>
                Дополнительно:<br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="ONION">лук (+ 20 тугриков, 5 ккал)<br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="SPICE">специи (+ 15 тугриков, + 0 ккал)<br>
                <br>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <button id="burgerValue" onclick="OrderHamburger()">Конечная стоимость и калорийность</button>
        <span id="burgerPrice"></span><span>грн</span><span id="burgerEnergy"></span><span> ккал</span>
    </div>
</form>


<script src="task.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

не работает не прибавляет.
Как реализовать на "input" прибавление

Answer (score 1):

```
var hamburger1 = new Hamburger ();
```

и

```
function Hamburger(size, stuffing) {
  if (!!size.param && !!stuffing.param) {
```

Чините.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример немного в лоб как можно сделать без дополнительных таблиц

```js
    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        
        // пройти по всем элементам и подсчитать суммарные значения
        let checks_elements = document.querySelectorAll('.checks');
        
        let price_total = 0;
        let weight_total = 0;
        
        for (let element of checks_elements) {
            if (element.checked == true) {
                const price = parseInt(element.getAttribute('attr-price'));
                price_total += price;
                
                const weight = parseInt(element.getAttribute('attr-weight'));
                weight_total += weight;
            }           
        }
        
        // вывести результат
        document.querySelector('.result').value = "цена: " + price_total.toString() + ", " + "вес: " + weight_total.toString();
    })
```

```html
<input type = 'checkbox' class = 'checks' attr-price="50" attr-weight="10">+50 цены, +10 веса
<br>
<input type = 'checkbox' class = 'checks' attr-price="20" attr-weight="-5">+20 цены, -5 веса
<br>
<input type = 'text' class = 'result' value = '0'>
```

Comment: просто нужно программу, расчитывающую стоимость и калорийность гамбургера. Используя ООП подход

Comment: я хочу чтобы, при выборе `input` добавлялись параметры
    `var hamburger1 = new Hamburger(orderHamburger.SIZE_SMALL, orderHamburger.STUFFING_CHEESE);`